# Make pages inaccessible from URLs and only accessible from clicking links on the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, session, url

I need to make each page in the website accessible only from the link that was pressed in the previous page. I.e. if someone copy pastes the URL into a new tab/window/browser, it will just redirect to an error page.

In other words, how do I make each link on a page just 1-time use?

I am using .NET 4.0, Visual Studio 2010 and ASP. NET Webforms.

Comment: You might try session storage. e.g. set something in session storage on the main page and then check on the "next" page if that variable is set.

Answer (score 0):

Try generating a query string as part of the url then validate that you have a valid query string otherwise redirect to 404

Comment: Thank you, this was what I was thinking as well. But my issue is, if i generate some kind of random number and attach it to all links on the page, if someone copies a link then pastes it in a different tab/browser, it will work since the link has a valid query string! I want so that they can't ever just copy paste links and have it work.

Comment: That’s part of what I mean by validate, as in check that the value has not been used otherwise redirect to 404